# How to implement order workflow navigating between multiple screen using spring or struts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts2, logic

This may not be a technical question, but looking for techniques to implement order workflow in spring or spring-struts web application.

My requirement is as follows
Below are the workflow steps to create an order

> 1. Search and select from the customer list
> 2. Validate the customer is entitled to receive the product (user need to select from the options)
> 3. Search and select the product
> 4. Select the category of product (eg. assume it is a book, whether the user needs a hard copy or soft copy)
> 5. Adds to the order, at this time a NO order # will be created
> 6. The user can perform the same steps 2 till 4 again, the new item will be saved to the order this happens only in the SCREEN or CLIENT SIDE.
> 7. user now clicks the save button, a unique order # will be generated.

Any suggestion is welcomed on how to implement this workflow.
The catch is that step 1 through 6 should be displayed in the screen and shouldn't be saved to database. The user can quit closing the order at any point during the order creation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Spring Webflow](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/)? It was designed for handling workflow/wizard type web applications. It also has an "end-state" concept that allows actions to occur when a flow has been completed, like persisting the work to a database (what happens is completely to the discretion of the developer). It's been a while since I last used it, but I would highly recommend it for your issue.

Comment: I will give a try. Using spring webflow

Answer (score 1):

There are two struts plugins which may help you:

**Struts Conversation**

http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/

**Struts 2 Action Flow**

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2PLUGINS/ActionFlow+Plugin